# Safe to use odbc link betw Filemaker 11 Server & SQL Server 2012?

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2012, odbc, filemaker

I’ve established a successful odbc connection between filemaker 11 Server and SQL Server 2012. Filemaker, inc has not certified this compatibility between the two but I have had no problems importing data from the sql database into filemaker. Does anyone know of risks utilizing the two databases? I need to understand better why this  connection works and why FileMaker’s specifications don’t include SQL 2012 Server!

Comment: What do their specifications include? If your database works with ODBC, then anything else that also works with ODBC should work. This is kind of like asking if a CSV file created via a text editor will work, since it wasn't created via Excel (CSV files can be created in text editors just fine).

Comment: Filemaker 11 supports these odbc drivers when working with External SQL data sources:

Answer (score 0):

Filemaker 11 was released in 2010. SQL Server 2012 was released in (surprisingly enough) 2012.

So, the Filemaker 11 documentation wouldn't list SQL Server 2012 as supported, because it wasn't released yet. When I looked for documentation online, I found the "Filemaker 11 ODBC and JDBC Guide", which has a 2010 copyright date.

By FileMaker 15, the documentation doesn't list explicit versions of other products it does or doesn't work with. It just days it works with products Like Oracle, SQL Server, and MySQL (no specific versions listed).

Since:

- Every version of SQL Server from 2000 on that was out when FileMaker 11 was released was listed as working with it,
- Later versions don't bother listing versions, but still show SQL Server as something they work with, and
- You're successfully able to query it now

I wouldn't think there would be any unexpected risks in using them together.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree and understand. If there had been any compatibility issues with importing data, I would have already run into them. It seems obvious, that it is a valid odbc source so I hope our IT Director makes the right decision and let’s me use a perfectly fine connection. Most questions here relate to not being able to connect so I appreciate you taking your time to respond!

Comment: One last comment, FileMaker Co. no longer even supports version 11 so it’s unlikely that they’ll validate or certify anything related since they’re well onto version 16 already!

Comment: Hi, the site doesn't want to take my thumbs-up vote for you, i'm too new i guess. And I'd still like an answer that will help me win over my IT Director that there's no risk, even though it seems obvious and logical. I give you 10 thumbs-up and I really do appreciate your comments.